# displaying data from database in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to rails and I can't figure out how exactly to get data from the database and have it show up in a partial. So I have a `question_form` partial:

```
<h1>Add question here</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= form_for(:question, url: questions_path) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose question..." %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
       <!-- ref 398, 664 -->
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I render it in my `root_path` (staticpages#home). It POSTs to a create action in a Questions controller which saves it to the database. I want to then display all of the questions submitted at once. I know I can do something like:

```
def show
@questions = Question.all
end
```

then iterate through @students in `show.html.erb`. But the problem is I don't want it in a separate page, I want it all to be shown on the homepage as well. How should I do this?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the instance variable to the show action for your *StaticPagesController*:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def show
  @questions = Question.all
  # ... Code to render pages/:page
  end
```

And then iterate *@questions* on the view:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<%= question.content %>
<% end %>
```